# Sql conditional query on table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables.

I am trying to get all columns from `articles` 
- and the number of status where status = 0 as `status0`
- and the number of status where status = 1 as `status1`

"Get all from articles and for each article row get the number of comments where status = 0 as status0 and get the number of comments where status = 1 as status1". Possible?

Tables:

```
articles
========
id   name
---------
1    abc
2    def
3    ghi


comments
========
id   article_id    status
-------------------------
1    2             1
2    2             0
3    1             0
4    3             1
```

Expected result of articles combined with status numbers:

```
id   name    status0   status1
------------------------------
1    abc     1         0
2    def     1         1
3    ghi     0         1
```

I am using Eloquent of Laravel, but would be sufficient to see the raw sql statement. I have no clue how to query and count these status.

---

Thanks to fiddle I have managed to create this query, but I get an error: Note that (`articles = db_surveys` and `comments = db_answers`)

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`status=1) status1` from `db_surveys` left join `db_answers` on `db_surveys`.`i' at line 1 (SQL: select `db_surveys`.`*, SUM(db_answers`.`status=0) status0, SUM(db_answers`.`status=1) status1` from `db_surveys` left join `db_answers` on `db_surveys`.`id` = `db_answers`.`surveyid` where `db_surveys`.`userid` = 6oGxr)"
```

Full query:

```
"select `db_surveys`.`*, SUM(db_answers`.`status=0) status0, SUM(db_answers`.`status=1) status1` from `db_surveys` left join `db_answers` on `db_surveys`.`id` = `db_answers`.`surveyid` where `db_surveys`.`userid` = 123 group by `db_surveys`.`id`"
```

---

**

### Final query:

**

```
SELECT 
  `s`.*,
   SUM(`a`.`status`='pending') `status0`, 
   SUM(`a`.`status`='confirmed') `status1` 
FROM
  `db_surveys` s
  LEFT JOIN `db_answers` a
    ON `s`.`id` = `a`.`surveyid` 
WHERE `s`.`userid` = '6oGxr' 
GROUP BY `s`.`id`
```

Comment: and what have you 'tried'?

Comment: SELECT s.*,count(s.status=0),count(s.status=1)
FROM articles s
LEFT JOIN comments a ON(s.id = a.article_id)
GROUP BY s.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sum() with expression to get the count on basis your conditions,using expression in sum will result as boolean o or 1

```
SELECT a.*
,SUM(`status` =0) status0   
,SUM(`status` =1) status1   
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN comments c ON(a.id = c.article_id)
GROUP BY a.id
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59e0c1/1)

**Edit**  In your original query you are not using back-ticks properly

```
SELECT 
  `s`.*,
   SUM(`a`.`status`=0) `status0`, 
   SUM(`a`.`status`=1) `status1` 
FROM
  `db_surveys` s
  LEFT JOIN `db_answers` a
    ON `s`.`id` = `a`.`surveyid` 
WHERE `s`.`userid` = 123 
GROUP BY `s`.`id`
```

Comment: Thanks the fiddle works! In my query I also have a `where`. Although I setup the query like you, I get an error. Please see my edit. I am using `db_answers`.`status` because `db_surveys` also has a column `status`

Comment: @Indianer see my updated answer you are not using proper back-ticks

Comment: DO you happen to know how to set an default value 0 to the sum of the status? Because I get a default "undefined" if there are no status found.

Comment: I guess you are asking for the null values returned from sum for this you can use somthing like *`COALESCE(SUM(a.status='pending')) status0`*

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(c.*) AS status0, COUNT(c2.*) AS status1
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.article_id = a.id AND c.status = 0
LEFT JOIN comments AS c2 ON c.article_id = a.id AND c.status = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the pretiest one, but it work :

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.name, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE article_id = articles.id AND status = 0), 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE article_id = articles.id AND status = 1) 
FROM articles;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/123b68/4